# Cutting off polygons that exceed world boundaries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, outline

I have some polygons that exceed the boundaries of the world map on the latitude. Basically, they stick out of the world map overlay at the left and right side of the screen. This is causing them to overlap when I load them in the software I use the view the exported shapefile.

I got much more polygons than in this mockup but I cannot share the original data. I use diffuse to create a single outline.

[image: mockup]

The problem is that the green and red polygons create an overlap in my shapefile viewer because they exceed the world map.
In the case of the green polygon, the problem can be solved if there is a way to cut off the data beyond the world map because the shape is the same.
In case of the red polygon, the part that is outside the world map doesn't exist at the right side of the screen so somehow that part can't be cut.
The part that overflow needs to be copied to the left side of the world map or the overflowing data should not create overlaps.

Basically, I want to create outlines only polygon. This is working, except for those couple of polygons that create overlap because they exceed the world map.

Comment: create an extension of your canvas to its size, cut your polygons and delete unnecessary cut polygons ...

Comment: I used a different work around. I used split parts to cut up the polygons and delete the parts I don't need. This is not a 100% perfect solution but it works in my case as the part of the polygon I couldn't move was overlapped anyway.